# perf dTLB does not work on EC2 instances

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, performance

perf dTLB does not work on my amzn linux EC2 instance, it says "not supported":

```
perf stat -e dTLB-loads,dTLB-load-misses,dTLB-stores,dTLB-store-misses -a -I 1000
#           time             counts unit events
     1.001380234    <not supported>      dTLB-loads               
     1.001380234    <not supported>      dTLB-load-misses         
     1.001380234    <not supported>      dTLB-stores              
     1.001380234    <not supported>      dTLB-store-misses        
     2.001615648    <not supported>      dTLB-loads
```

is there any way to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, MMU/TLB statistics are served by processor-specific performance counters. As AWS run on virtualized Xen/KVM instances, you don't have direct access to the underlying processor and its performance counters.